# Android SDK compact

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android 23 build tools,but my imported project support only android 19,how to compact with this or how to fix it.
I see the followinf error in logcat,

```
"Failed to sync Gradle project 'My Application1'
    Error:Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-19' in: E:\Android\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>"
```

This is my build.gradle file"

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules. 
buildscript { 
     repositories { 
        jcenter() 
     }
     dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' 
     }
} 
allprojects { 
  repositories { 
      jcenter() 
  } 
}
```

This is my `module/build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 

android { 
     compileSdkVersion 19 
     buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" 

     defaultConfig { 
            applicationId "com.appsrox.remindme" 
            minSdkVersion 7 
            targetSdkVersion 8 
     }
     buildTypes { 
         release { 
            minifyEnabled false 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt' 
         } 
      } 
 }
```

Comment: May be you are using same wrong values in your build.gradle file or you are compiling with an sdk that you have to download with your SDK Manager. Post your build.gradle file.

Comment: This is my build.gradle file"// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}"

Comment: this is my imported project build.gradle file                                                       "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appsrox.remindme"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}"""

Comment: I have just added your comments in the original question

Answer (score 0):

> Error:Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-19'

It happens when the Android-19 sdk **is not installed**.
Open your  **SDK Manager** and check to see if Android 4.4 (API 19) is installed.

Pay attention using the latest support libraries. The v23.x.x require compileSdk 23

About :

> my imported project support only android 19

you should check the difference between `compileSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion`, and `targetSdkVersion`.

`compileSdkVersio`n is your way to tell Gradle **what version of the Android SDK to compile your app with**. Using the new Android SDK is a requirement to use any of the new APIs added in that level.

`minSdkVersion` **is the lower bound for your app**. The minSdkVersion is one of the signals the Google Play Store uses to determine which of a user’s devices an app can be installed on.

`targetSdkVersion` **is the main way Android provides forward compatibility by not applying behavior changes unless the targetSdkVersion is updated**

More [info here](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#.v16nkpd0m).